# Error al hacer un insert con un campo vacio mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema con la inserción de datos en una tabla.

El caso es que al hacer la inserción no me coje el campo `''` como un valor `null` o `0` simplemente me salta error. Ya he comprobado la tabla y el campo ese en concreto no tiene ninguna restricción de clave primaria, valor no nulo, etc.

Adjunto la consulta:

```
​insert into usuarios.comida(codigo, usuario, codbinsa, fecha, invitado, pedido, hora)
values ('1cb1e6c756', 0300, '0300', '2018-02-05', '', 'Paella Habas Alcachofa. MERLUZA PLANCHA. Couland. |', '0950');
```

El problema según el error, por lo que he entendido, es que no convierte el `''` en un valor `INT` o `NULL` sino que lo considera como el *string* cadena vacía.

Espero su ayuda.

Comment: Si la columna es de tipo entero no deberías pasarle un _string_. ¿Por qué no le pasas `0` en vez de `''`? ¿De qué tipo son las columnas?

Answer (score 0):

Para que te guarde el valor como `NULL` has de especificarlo directamente, sin comillas.

```
​insert into usuarios.comida(codigo,usuario,codbinsa,fecha,invitado,pedido,hora) values ('1cb1e6c756',0300,'0300','2018-02-05', NULL,'Paella Habas Alcachofa. MERLUZA PLANCHA. Couland. |','0950');
```

Te dejo mas información: [aqui](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/insert-select-update-null-value_t)

Answer (score 0):

No estaba muy seguro de ello y he trasteado un poco sobre el tema llegando a las siguientes conclusiones:

-He intentado introducir strings utilizando las comillas simples `' '` en columnas que esperaban un `int`. Al insertar un valor nulo como en tu caso `''`; el insert se realizaba pero saltaba una excepción:

[image: Test]

Aún así al mirar la tabla automáticamente se introducía el valor 0.

Al introducir un numero entre comillas `'2'` el numero se introducía correctamente en la tabla a pesar de indicar que es un `string`.

**Explicacion:** Por defecto el formato SQL no lo aceptaría, sin embargo hay excepciones como MySQL, Oracle, etc que aceptan este tipo de sintaxis. Cuando pones las comillas, el valor introducido dentro es interpretado como un `String` y en casos particulares como los mencionados, antes de que se ejecute la query MySQL automaticamente intenta cambiar el formato de `String` a `Int`, El problema con esto es que puede dar varios resultados:

- Se ejecuta de forma correcta
- Da error y no se ejecuta la query
- El numero es interpretado y el resultado es diferente al introducido(cambia a otros numeros,las comillas se mueven, el valor cambia,etc)

Por lo tanto no es muy recomendable utilizar este método no solo por la interpretación sino porque también aunque de forma mínima aumenta la carga de la consulta por el simple hecho de poner 2 comillas.

**Recomendacion**

SQL esta preparado para reaccionar a cada tipo de datos de una forma diferente. No se recomienda nunca poner comillas alrededor de números de la misma forma que tampoco poner números en sitios donde se espera un `String` o un `Boolean`, cada tipo de dato tiene sus características y es interpretado de forma diferente para optimizar el funcionamiento.

La query la puedes ejecutar de las siguientes maneras:

1. Poniendo directamente un numero 0 en el valor:

   ```
   insert into usuarios.comida(codigo, usuario, codbinsa, fecha, invitado, pedido, hora)
   values ('1cb1e6c756', 0300, '0300', '2018-02-05', 0, 'Paella Habas Alcachofa. MERLUZA PLANCHA. Couland. |', '0950');
   ```
2. Poniendo un valor `NULL`:

   ```
   insert into usuarios.comida(codigo, usuario, codbinsa, fecha, invitado, pedido, hora)
   values ('1cb1e6c756', 0300, '0300', '2018-02-05', NULL, 'Paella Habas Alcachofa. MERLUZA PLANCHA. Couland. |', '0950');
   ```
3. O simplemente no indicando que vas a introducir dicho valor y dejar que se ponga por defecto el valor (mi recomendación)

   ```
   insert into usuarios.comida(codigo, usuario, codbinsa, fecha, pedido, hora)
   values ('1cb1e6c756', 0300, '0300', '2018-02-05', 'Paella Habas Alcachofa. MERLUZA PLANCHA. Couland. |', '0950');
   ```

Fuentes: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976/mysql-quote-numbers-or-not) [link2](https://www.sigmainfy.com/blog/sql-single-quotes-for-numeric-values-is-it-really-good-practice.html)